# How to calculate bit mask and bit shift values based on the following 3 fixed values?

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, bitwise-and

I am supposed to determine the bit mask and shift values based on the following 3 values: the start byte, the start bit, and the number of bits.

I will receive some byte array for my data of x many bytes. Let's say some random chunk of data within this large byte array represents whether a light switch is on or off. So I will focus on this single byte/8-bits of data for this example. 3 bits out of these 8 bits are used to determine the on/off state of the light switch.

So, all I know about this chunk of data are these 3 fixed values: the starting byte position within this byte array, the starting bit position within this specific byte itself, and the number of bits allocated to represent the on/off state of this light switch.

So in this particular example, the byte position is byte 15 (within this large byte array of x many bytes). The starting bit position is 0. The number of bits is 3 (since 3 bits are allocated within this byte to represent on/off state).

My question is: how do I calculate the bit mask and bit shift value based on these 3 fixed values? I know the calculation might involve base 2 or raising to the power of 2, but unsure.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a pretty common task and therefore problably a duplicate. Have you tried to search for similar question? Either way, please add a programming language to your tags.

Comment: Yes I have, however I need the mathematical formula/calculation for this problem which I wasn't able to find

Comment: I couldn't find a duplicate for C#, therefore I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Given a byte array with the following indexing scheme ...

```
byte ,--0---, ,--1---, ,--2---, ...
bit  76543210 76543210 76543210 ...
```

You can extract a bit sequence inside a single (!) byte using the following method

```
public byte extract(byte[] array, int startByte, int startBit, int numberOfBits)  {
  return  (byte) ((array[startByte] >> startBit) & ~(-1 << numberOfBits));
}
```

startBit + numberOfBits must be ≤ 8. Otherwise the addressed bit sequence would span across multiple bytes in the array. In this case you can apply the very same principle to the next bytes concatenated together:

```
public uint extract32(byte[] array, int startByte, int startBit, int numberOfBits)  {
  ulong block =
      ((ulong) array[(startByte+4) % array.Length] << 32)
    | ((ulong) array[(startByte+3) % array.Length] << 24)
    | ((ulong) array[(startByte+2) % array.Length] << 16) 
    | ((ulong) array[(startByte+1) % array.Length] << 8)
    |  (ulong) array[startByte];
  return (uint) ((block >> startBit) & ~(ulong.MaxValue << numberOfBits));
}
```

Since `uint` has 32 bits, numberOfBits must be ≤ 32.

**Example:**

```
extract32(new byte[] {0x10, 0x32, 0x54, 0x76, 0x98, 0xBA}, 1, 4, 32);
```

extracts `0xA9876543`.

Comment: [Bitwise and shift operators in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators)